Knowing where you are at in a progression during Improvisation
I'm sure this has been asked a million times but I cant find it.
I have a hard time listening and playing at the same time. Knowing exactly which beat we are on so I can play to the chord changes. I'm either listening and not playing or playing and missing the changes all the time.
What's the key to this ?

@Aaron My answer here is better than the ones in that other question!

@piiperiReinstateMonica then consider moving it there.

@piiperiReinstateMonica Agreed; it's not only a duplicate but is by the same user, four years ago.

@AndyBonner LOL maybe it's time for a different approach if the OP has been following the accepted advice for four years without any progress. ;) Extreme duplicate yeah. Well at least the actual question text contained different words this time.

@Aaron I added an answer to the other one. This is one of the funniest questions ever, same guy asks the exact same thing after four years. Music.se is clearly not a short-term quick-fix site, people have some true longevity here. (And the site's automatic dupe-finder is totally useless because even the same person doesn't get their own question back when asking the same thing again)

"I'm either listening and not playing or playing and missing" —One point: leaving "holes" in your solo can be its own skill and virtue. Who says you have to play all the time? Be like a painter, use that negative space!

@piiperiReinstateMonica good catch. I completely missed that it was the same poster. It seems 2020’s advice didn’t take.

I answered on the older version of your question. https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/102250/how-can-you-listen-and-judge-where-you-are-in-the-music-whilst-improvising

It seems the thing to ask the OP is to edit this question and explained what has happened during all that time and try to explain why/how things aren't working.

Laurence already said it: practice. But WHAT to practice, is the real question. I give the following advice and plan for your practice routing:
Do not play over the chords, play the chords. You do the accompaniment, either by rhythmically playing the actual full chords, or arpeggiating, if it's a non-chordal instrument. Then start adding improvised notes among the comping. First ONE improvised non-accompaniment note per bar. Then two notes.
Even when you're playing solo, you have to have the chord-playing accompanist attitude and perspective going on in your head all the time. A strong sense of time and chord structure, like an accompanist has to have. Time is even more important than getting all the notes.
So, let me repeat.

Phase 1 : you comp ONLY. 100% rhythmic comping, following the chord chart PERFECTLY in PERFECT TIMING.
Phase 2 : you comp, but you play a maximum of ONE improvised solo note per bar.
Phase 3 : you comp, but you play a maximum of TWO improvised solo notes per bar.
... etc.
Final phase: YOU STILL COMP IN YOUR MIND even if  as an artistic choice, your solo has no notes at all, or you play a million notes of fast shredding (as an artistic choice). You still comp, you play the rhythm in your head at the same time.

If you practice with backing tracks, do NOT use ones with chordal instruments. Drums and bass only. IMO the best way is with no backing track at all, with a metronome only. You comp, you are the rhythm section. You play the rhythm and you outline the chords, even if you're the soloist.
That's how you learn to do it. It will be impossible to lose track of where you are in the changes because you play the changes all the time. That's your main job. Adding solo notes is of secondary importance. At first your solo notes may just add a few embellishments here and there, but as you get better and you develop a feeling for the chords, you start being more melodic. But you never lose track of the chords, because playing the chords is your primary task, even if people see you as a soloist.
In my opinion, if you're playing a nice melodic solo, the chord changes can still be somehow heard in your solo lines. And it comes just naturally, because you've made it your top priority to play the chords and the rhythm all the time.

You know the answer to this really, don't you?  :-)  Practice.  There's no magic bullet that will remove this problem, just  develop fluency with your instrument and with playing over chords.  If you're not technically fluent, and have to THINK too hard about what notes fit the chord, you'll lose touch with the beat.    Don't worry, it will improve!
Are you reading the chord sequence from a page?  I find it much easier to keep my place with something to look at.  Give it a try.

Looks like this question is an extreme case of duplicate, so I encourage you to work this into your answer from four years ago on the dup.
